# How do I set an Outlook rule on bulk email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

My company gets lots of bulk email where the "**To**:" field and "**From**:" field are identical so the **Sender** and **Recipient** match. My email address, along with many others are hidden in BCC.

How do I configure an Outlook rule to move all such emails to a specific folder if I can't use wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any similarities on these sender/recipients? If so, maybe this condition for rules could work for you.

[image]

If you think it would be helpful to create a rule with wildcard in Outlook, you could also try to create a rule with a script to check, for more information, you could refer to this article: [To create a rule with wildcards](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/create-a-rule-with-wildcards/)